problems with bluetoothdriver
is it possible to include this drivers in the next ubuntu update?
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=57117d7234dadfba2a83615b2a9369f6f2f9914f
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=e11523e97f474f8c7acc76fa912209900e2d3c69
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=23fcb27b33c8ca09a371de5bc95a18c20f72709c
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=e4412654e260842e1a94ffe0d4026e8a6fd34246
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=6932627425d6d3849aecd43c02158a5312895ad4
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=8c0d17b6b06c5bef45de7e08c5c3cab8367f6cbc
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=09a19d6dd974c677669eff44a9044f65d7be359d

This is a question and answer site for the support of Ubuntu and related products. The volunteers here can not help with this off topic issue. Sorry.

Why don't you change this to a support question and include the Ubuntu version and kernel you are using?  Most of those commits are 2 years old and should be in the 6.8 Ubuntu kernel used in 24.04
